# bebop2 modified CV build version of program creates SIGSEGV on raspberry pi 3

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi3, segmentation-fault

I am trying to navigate bebop2 autonomously using raspberry pi 3. I am getting the raw format from bebop2 and decoding it using ffmpeg. It runs completely fine on intel architecture. I tried to cross compile it for arm and it was successful. It runs fine but after a few seconds it crashes and gives SIGSEGV fault. I have tried gdb to bt the problem but it gives an error of memcpy() from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnuaebihf/libarmmem.so.

I tried to remove the non-arm instructions dependencies in the first place; https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29117/process-terminate-with-sigill-using-valgrind/66621#66621

But then I got an error of memcpy.S no such file or directory.

I don't know what to do and I am stuck now.

[EDIT:1]

**valgrind output:**

```
valgrind ./Controller
==1361== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1361== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1361== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1361== Command: ./Controller
==1361== 
./Controller
==1361== Invalid read of size 8
==1361==    at 0x4845004: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1cc50c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 18 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833970: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==1361==    by 0xAFC77B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6.3.2)
==1361== 
==1361== Invalid read of size 4
==1361==    at 0x4845030: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1cc72c is 20 bytes inside a block of size 22 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833970: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==1361==    by 0xAFC77B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6.3.2)
==1361== 
==1361== Invalid read of size 8
==1361==    at 0x484501C: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1ccf9c is 20 bytes inside a block of size 26 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833970: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==1361==    by 0xAFC77B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6.3.2)
==1361== 
==1361== Invalid read of size 8
==1361==    at 0x4844FEC: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1d59ac is 28 bytes inside a block of size 34 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833970: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==1361==    by 0xAFC77B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6.3.2)
==1361== 
==1361== Invalid read of size 8
==1361==    at 0x4844F8C: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1e7a24 is 20 bytes inside a block of size 26 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833970: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==1361==    by 0xAFC77B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6.3.2)
==1361== 
disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xEE190F1D
                 cond=14(0xE) 27:20=225(0xE1) 4:4=1 3:0=13(0xD)
==1361== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0xcc78de8.
==1361==    at 0xCC78DE8: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1361== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==1361== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==1361== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==1361==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==1361==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==1361== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==1361==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==1361==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==1361== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==1361== probably kill your program.
==1361== Invalid read of size 4
==1361==    at 0x4844BB8: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1eb788 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 50 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833F2C: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:282)
==1361==    by 0x77EC9E7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==1361== 
==1361== Invalid read of size 4
==1361==    at 0x4844FA0: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361==  Address 0xd1eb7f0 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 50 alloc'd
==1361==    at 0x4833F2C: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:282)
==1361==    by 0x77EC9E7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==1361== 
disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200
                 cond=15(0xF) 27:20=16(0x10) 4:4=0 3:0=0(0x0)
==1361== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x48426f4.
==1361==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==1361== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==1361== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==1361==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==1361==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==1361== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==1361==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==1361==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==1361== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==1361== probably kill your program.
==1361== 
==1361== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==1361==  Illegal opcode at address 0x48426F4
==1361==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1361== 
==1361== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1361==     in use at exit: 541,641 bytes in 1,173 blocks
==1361==   total heap usage: 1,980 allocs, 807 frees, 571,016 bytes allocated
==1361== 
==1361== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1361==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1361==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1361==      possibly lost: 410,404 bytes in 190 blocks
==1361==    still reachable: 131,237 bytes in 983 blocks
==1361==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1361== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1361== 
==1361== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1361== ERROR SUMMARY: 24 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction
```

**bt output:**

```
(gdb) bt 
#0 0x76fbc3a0 in memcmp () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so 
#1 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

**disassemble output (0x76fbc3a0):**

```
=> 0x76fbc3a0 <+7344>:  vldmiacs    r1!, {d7}
```

**x/5i $pc output:**

```
(gdb) x/5i $pc
=> 0x76fbc3a0 <memcmp+7344>:    vldmiacs    r1!, {d7}
   0x76fbc3a4 <memcmp+7348>:    vstmiami    r0!, {s13}
   0x76fbc3a8 <memcmp+7352>:    vstmiacs    r0!, {d7}
   0x76fbc3ac <memcmp+7356>:    lsls    lr, r12, #27
   0x76fbc3b0 <memcmp+7360>:    vldmiami    r1!, {d2-d3}
```

Comment: Please, post full gdb `bt` output, probably there was error in someone who called memcpy. "memcpy.S no such file or directory" is not a error (both for gdb and valgrind), it is warning, you can still see assembler from gdb with `disassemble` command and `x/5i $pc`. What is the full output of valgrind?

Comment: @osgx, see the outputs.

Comment: Can you recompile full project with `-fno-omit-frame-pointers` (and probably `-g`) gcc (or other [compiler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0774g/vvi1466179578564.html)) option added and gather valgring/gdb logs again (with additional gdb's `info reg` and `disassemble`)? What was modified in the project? What is full name of project you want to compile and run and where is full source code was downloaded (which patches applied?). Valgrind output already says about some (non-critical?) errors near malloc/free usage.

Comment: I am using `ccmake`. I don't know how to use `-fno-omit-frame-pointers`.

I modified **arsdk_products/blob/master/native/config/product.mk** as 
`TARGET_CPU = pi3`
and
**alchemy/blob/master/toolchains/cpu.mk** as
`ifeq ("$(TARGET_CPU)","pi3")
TARGET_GLOBAL_CFLAGS += -march=armv7-a
TARGET_FLOAT_ABI ?= hard
endif`

The project is basically an sdk for bebop2 called ARSDK through which I manipulated `mat` objects for OpenCV to implement detection and tracking mechanism and the output of this mechanism determines the movement of the bebop2.